# Put time limit on Jest test?

Tags: node.js, npm, jestjs

I'm running a set of tests with Jest to demonstrate Big O using two different methods for Fibonacci.

```
const fastFib = require('./../fastFib');
const slowFib = require('./../slowFib');

test('Fast way of getting Fibonacci of 44', () => {
  expect(fastFib(44)).toBe(701408733);
});

test('Slow way of getting Fibonacci of 44', () => {
  expect(slowFib(44)).toBe(701408733);
});
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to specify the maximum length of a test? I saw you can pass a third variable for an async timeout but it doesn't seem to have any effect on normal functions:

```
test('Slow way of getting Fibonacci of 44', () => {
  expect(slowFib(44)).toBe(701408733);
}, 5000);
```

Is there a way I can specify the maximum execution time for a function with Jest?

---

I will share `slowFib.js` for reference:

```
function fib(n) {
  return (n<=1) ? n : fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
}

module.exports = fib;
```

Comment: I think that [here](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/6947) you can have more details about this. Basically there is an open discussion on it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

so your test pauses because of sync execution - there is no way to interrupt that by timeout. You need to "split execution". Next version fails to me:

```
test('Slow way of getting Fibonacci of 44', (done) => {
  expect(slowFib(44)).toBe(701408733);
  setTimeout(done, 10); // smallest timeout possible to make different macrotask
}, 5000);
```

PS I also believe this should be achievable by marking test `async` but have not yet figured how exactly.

[UPD] you actually may achieve your goal without using test's timeout:

```
test('Slow way of getting Fibonacci of 44', () => {
  const start = new Date();
  expect(slowFib(44)).toBe(701408733);
  expect(new Date() - start).toBeLessThan(5000);
});
```

Comment: It still passes for me. I've updated my question with the contents of `slowFib.js`, maybe that makes a difference?

Comment: it fails to me. not sure, how to debug. what version of Jest do you use?

Comment: package.json says "jest": "^24.8.0"

Comment: what version are you using?

Comment: I'm using "23.6.0"

Comment: Hey, thanks for the update! Just seeing it now, a bit of a hack but it works perfect! Going to make one test to check correct result and another to verify it completes under a certain time.

Comment: glad to help! anyway actually have no idea why timeout in `it()` does not work to you

Answer (score 1):

In your test file you can set
`jest.setTimeout(5000);` which overrides the default timeout for a test case in jest

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need to implement your own timer (with setTimeout or using Promises). One alternative would be to use the async keyword for your function to make it work with the built-in parameter :

```
test('Slow way of getting Fibonacci of 44', async () => {
  expect(slowFib(44)).toBe(701408733);
}, 5000);
```

Comment: thanks but the test still passes even though it takes longer than 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a (typescript friendly) functions inspired by @skyboyer's suggestion.
(tested using Jest 24.8.0, but should be relevant to any version)

```
// Takes a threshold and a callback.
// if the callback didn't run within the threshold, the returned function will evaluate to a rejected promise.
// else, the returned function will evaluate to a resolved promise with the value returned by 'cb' (T)
const resolveWithin = <T>(threshold: number, cb: () => T): () => Promise<T> => {
  return () => {
    const start = Date.now();

    return Promise.resolve(cb()).then((t: T) => {
      const elapsed = Date.now() - start;

      if (elapsed > threshold) {
        return Promise.reject(elapsed);
      }

      return Promise.resolve(t);
    });
  }
};

// Uses "resolveWithin" to ensure a test has run within the threshold.
const withIn = <T>(threshold: number, fn: () => T): () => Promise<T> => {
  const cb = resolveWithin(threshold, fn);

  // @ts-ignore
  return () => {
    return cb().catch((elapsed) => {
      expect(elapsed).toBeLessThanOrEqual(threshold);
    })
  }
};

it("example", withIn(1000, () => { ... }));

it("example", withIn(1000, async () => { ... }));
```

A note regarding @Khaled Osman's / @HRK44 answers.

From what I could tell, using either approach will not be reflected as a test failure, and will not appear in reports generated by Jest.